# CakePHP 1.3: How not to delete the image when admin_delete is called

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

**EDIT**: UPDATING MY QUESTION FOR MORE CLARIFICATION

**==========================================================**

I use MeioUpload to upload pictures. The picture location is placed in the DB `users` table in `image` as such:`/img/uploads/users/img/picture34.png`.

When a user is deleted, CakePHP is also accessing the physical location of this image from `User.image` and deleting that image.

There is no belongTo/HasMany relationship here as I do not have an image model/controller.

How can I prevent CakePHP from physically deleting this image?

**==========================================================**

In my application I have the option to remove a user using the `admin_delete` function in my `users_controller.php`. However, when this function is called (see following function), the image saved in the DB is also deleted. How can I prevent this function from removing the image.

```
function admin_delete($id = null) {

    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Este usuario nao existe', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }

    if ($this->User->delete($id)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Este usuario ja foi removido', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }

    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Este usuario nao foi removido', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your controller code is not deleting the image. The Meio upload plugin is deleting it.

Comment: You are correct... I figured that out after some discussions with Daniel. I am now detaching this behavior when I call the `admin_delete` method. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

The Meioupload behavior defines this beforeDelete method:

```
/**
 * Deletes all files associated with the record beforing delete it.
 *
 * @author Vinicius Mendes
 * @param $model Object
 */
function beforeDelete(&$model) {
    $model->read(null, $model->id);
    if(isset($model->data)) {
        foreach($this->__fields as $field=>$options) {
            $file = $model->data[$model->name][$field];
            if($file && $file != $options['default'])
                $this->_deleteFiles($file, $options['dir']);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Since there is no option to don't delete the image I think the only way is to temporary detach the behavior. Couldn't test it but something like this could work:

```
function admin_delete($id = null) {
    $this->User->Behaviors->disable('MeioUpload');

    // your code

    $this->User->Behaviors->enable('MeioUpload');
}
```

===

I'm assuming the image is associated with the user model by a belongsTo/hasMany association? In this case the standard delete method has a [parameter to avoid deleting of associated data](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1036/delete), here is the definition of the delete function:

```
delete(int $id = null, boolean $cascade = true);
```

if you set *cascade* to false you associated image doesn't get deleted:

```
if ($this->User->delete($id,false)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Este usuario ja foi removido', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
}
```

Comment: I have done that and it does not work. Please see my question for more clarification....

Comment: sorry, I don't see any clarification in your question, at least I need to know how you associated your models. In my test case with a User hasMany Image and Image belongsTo User association the exact same function works as expected ... if you could post your User and Image models it would be easier to help

Comment: I placed the clarication on my original question... under EDIT. Anyway, I temporarily fixed the issued by accessing the MeioUpload behavior and commenting out `//$this->_deleteFiles($model, $file['field'], $file['name'], $file['dir']);` from the `function _deleteFilesList(&$model) {` function. I will work on developing a means, where I give the admin the option to choose whether or not they would like to delete a specific user's picture. Thank you for your efforts... However, I should definitely implement the solution/process you are talking about.

Comment: awesome, we got our wires crossed like three times :D I think detaching (if it works) is the more clean way, because you don't have to edit the plugin, glad you found a solution ...

Comment: I totally forgot about `detach`. Thanks so much. I have changed the MeioUpload behavior file back to its original and right in the beginning of the `admin_delete` method in my `user_controllers.php` file I added `$this->User->Behaviors->detach('MeioUpload');` and everything works as desired. This was a great suggestion..